# flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "app"

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template 
# Flask is a class that allows us to create an app
# render_template is a method offered by flask

app = Flask(__name__) # creates an app with the name of the file

@app.route('/') # route that listens to the homepage
def index(): # route handler
    # render_template(template_name_or_list) 
    # used to specify an html template to render to the user
    return render_template('index.html', data=[{
        'description': 'Todo 1'
    }, {
        'description': 'Todo 2'
    }, {
        'description': 'Todo 3'
    }])

# To run the app
# In the terminal
# FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run
```

My application's name is **app.py**, and it's in a folder named **ToDo-App**, and within this folder there is another folder called **templates**, that contains the **index.html** file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Todo App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <!-- jinja for loop -->
            {% for d in data %}
            <li>{{ d.description }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            <!--<li>Todo 1</li>
            <li>Todo 2</li>
            <li>Todo 3</li>
            <li>Todo 4</li>-->
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**In the terminal:**

Esam@DESKTOP-73QDAD3 MINGW32 /i/web/advanced-track/1-sql_and_data_modeling_for_the_web/ToDo-App
$ FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run

- Serving Flask app "app.py" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: on
- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 266-552-216
- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

When I opened this link **http://127.0.0.1:5000/**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Esam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 236, in locate_app
**import**(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Esam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 337, in **call**
rv = self._load_unlocked()
File "C:\Users\Esam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 324, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "C:\Users\Esam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 381, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "C:\Users\Esam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 246, in locate_app
raise NoAppException(
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "app".

Comment: did you find a solution?  I'm having the same problem.  I can run a production environment fine, but when I switch to development it kicks the error you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depend on what machine your using, you need to do one of the following:

Unix Bash (Linux, Mac, etc.):

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello
$ flask run
```

Windows CMD:

```
> set FLASK_APP=hello
> flask run
```

Windows PowerShell:

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
> flask run
```

Comment: How does this help?  I'm having the same problem, but can't find a resolution.